# How can I reduce (fold) an iterator and keep intermediate results (such as a cumulative sum)?

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to apply a reduction to an iterator, but I don't need just the final value, the intermediate results are important, too.

As an example, let's convert a vector of offsets to a vector of positions:

```
let offsets = vec![3, 2, 1, 4];
// create positions vector [3, 5, 6, 10]
```

My attempt at a solution uses [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) and a closure:

```
let mut acc = 0;
let positions: Vec<i32> = offsets
    .iter()
    .map(|x| {
        acc = acc + x;
        acc
    })
    .collect();
```

Good comment from @starblue: To do a cumulative sum, [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) would be the best option. It applies a reduction and returns the last value. It doesn't return intermediate solutions though:

```
// basically exact code from fold example in the docs
let last_position = offsets.iter().fold(0, |acc, x| acc + x);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I see that I should have read the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) more carefully. The function I'm looking for is called [`scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan). Here is a cumulative sum implementation:

```
let offsets = vec![3, 2, 1, 4];
let positions: Vec<i32> = offsets
    .iter()
    .scan(0, |acc, &x| {
        *acc = *acc + x;
        Some(*acc)
    })
    .collect();
```

Comment: You should probably use `fold` for the case where the values of the accumulator form the output. `scan` is more general, you can have arbitrary internal state independently of the values returned.

Comment: True, my question is a bit misleading. I am interested in all intermediate results, whereas fold just returns the last value. I agree that the cumulative sum is probably not a good example. I was thinking of numpy's cumsum when I posted this